# Network Analyses with Subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that I have a graph and I divided it to subgraphs which can be overlapping. I want to use these subgraphs in network analyses like centrality calculation, community detection etc. instead of using individual nodes.

Do you know any research about this topic?

Comment: Related video: [Enumeration of Automorphism Orbits of Graphlets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY1UkCPSKH8).

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be heading towards to topic of [*network motifs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_motif) (or *graphlets*), which are currently a hot research topic in a range of disciplines (e.g. computational biology).  Finding useful patterns is part of "network motif detection" and "frequent subgraph mining".  The literature is growing very rapidly in these areas.

Some examples that seem relevant to your question are:

- Dividing a network into subgraphs has applications in data compression.  If a subgraph appears numerous times over, it can be stored in a dictionary are copies are replaced by a dictionary reference.  (Papers on this topic can be found by searching for "network motif graph compression" or "frequent subgraph graph compression".)
- Networks can be compared (e.g. model networks vs. real-world networks) via their "graphlet degree distribution" (e.g. [ref.](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/23/2/e177.abstract)).

Comment: Good directions, thanks. I suspect my subgraphs are not being simple so I don't expect higher frequencies for different subgraphs. One other point I really care about is how do they interact with other subgraphs such as does a specific subgraph very central to main graph?

Comment: Another research about subgraps: http://people.cam.cornell.edu/~jugander/subgraphs/

Comment: Network motifs are quite similar to [graphlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphlets), but they have a subtle difference. [Network motifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_motif) are subgraphs that are statistically estimated to be more or less frequent than expected by a null model. Graphlets are not defined by any statistical properties, but by specifically being mutually non-isomorphic simple vertex-induced subgraphs. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY1UkCPSKH8) for an introduction to the latter.

Comment: Well, usually vertex induced... I suppose that one could induce graphlets using edges instead.